# MacOS - How to stop safari from opening app store when clicking https://apps.apple.com link?

Tags: macos, safari, applications, mac-appstore

On MacOS Ventura 13.3.1, Safari 16.4, when clicking any https://apps.apple.com on a website, the app store launches as well as the link opens in the browser (same tab or new tab).

I want Safari to STOP opening the App Store without asking, ideally not opening the App Store directly.

How can I stop Safari from opening the App Store when clicking https://apps.apple.com links (e.g. https://apps.apple.com/de/app/session-pal/id1515213004?l=en&mt=12) ?

Although this seems like a copy of [How to prevent safari from opening links in third party apps on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/413118/488395), I found the provided answer accepted answer not helpful, the commented solution does not apply for the Apple App store, also the other question is about "third party apps" while the App Store is an Apple App.

UPDATE:

Someone really closed the question claiming it a duplicate of this one, Can you stop websites from opening apps?, which is clearly about an iPad that runs iOS while this question is clearly about macOS, how can it be duplicate?

UPDATE 2:
Someone removed my update explaining why this question is not a duplicate, and it still considered a duplicate, why?

Comment: Who closed the question? The duplicate is clearly about iOS and this question is about macOS, WTF is wrong with you?

Comment: Universal links, are well, *universal.*. While the question is specifically about iOS, it applies to all browsers, mobile or desktop.  Did you try the solution?

Comment: As for your “edits” they need to differentiate your question sufficiently from the dupe (not just iOS versus macOS).  The edits, as currently written are basically just rants and not at all helpful.  (Also, terms like “WFT is wrong with you” can be considered aggressive in nature likely  won’t help your cause with folks here).

Comment: At least you gave an explanation now. "While the question is specifically about iOS, it applies to all browser". That doesn't make sense at all to me, because even the question tags are "ipad" and "Safari". As far as I know Stack Exchange, the tags always narrow down the environment, hence such a question only "belongs" to that environment. With you logic I could ask about a shortcut in xcode and a question for same shortcut for jetbrains IDE would be duplicate?

Comment: "The edits, as currently written are basically just rants and not at all helpful." They clearly state why I think this question is not a duplicate, what else should I do? Not to mention, I don't have the option to send you a private message asking you why you thought that would be a duplicate. It's not at all "helpful" and "aggressive" to just mark questions as duplicates without giving any reason first.

Comment: @Allan Just that I understand you: Even that the linked "duplicate" is about a whole different OS environment with a completely different version of Safari is NOT a reasonable argument that this is NOT a duplicate? The provided answer doesn't obviously work, because Safari on macOS has completely different context options...

Comment: [Apple is going for a new *unified* experience across all it’s platforms](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/) (you can see that in System Preferences in Ventura).  iOS is not so different from macOS as one would think and considering universal links apply to both mobile and desktop browsers, it is only prudent to start from this aspect and work our way out.

Comment: If the question is sufficiently different, nobody here will object to reopening.  Of this I have no doubt.  As for the reasoning behind closing and your jetbrains IDE example, that’s better addressed in [meta]

Comment: @Allan Even if you consider this a duplicate, nobody could ever give answer for macOS since the question you linked to is closed as being "unclear" (while somebody even understood it anyway and gave an answer, as well as you did). But hey if you wanna make SO and even worse place then it already is, good luck to you ;)

Comment: "that’s better addressed in Ask Different Meta", True that, I'm not gonna waste more time on this.